# Debugging C# project

Tags: c#, debugging

I am predominantly from Excel / VBA programming background, and I have worked on stand-alone small C#/ Winform projects.  Where I had to debug something or say change rename column - I just put breakpoints and debug flow.

Recently, I have been trying to look into to legacy C# solution which got 180 projects in solution, and I am looking to debug ,but struggling to check flow in  VS 2015.

My simple requirement: To rename a display name in on of the form, I thought its simple ,but struggling to understand where the display name is set.

1. When I click on Form ( say frm_Sales) in debug mode , I get all sort of errors, like below.

[image]

2. When I put break point and try to traverse, my code is not stopping at form_load event.
3. However, if I put messages, I get to see message displayed. But, debugger is not stopping at breakpoints.

How can I debug the flow? Normally in Excel / VBA I user Ctrl +Break to see where error is and to stop debugger and trace from there. But can't do in C#?

Comment: Which IDE are you using? are you debuggin in debug mode or in release mode? did you changed any default setting?   
When you set up the breakpoint, do they look like an empty red circle or the circle is filled up inside? 
Also, plese fix the image.

Comment: I am am using Debug mode in x64 in VS 2015, I do have full filled up circle - assuming breakpoints are not ignored. thanks fixed images.

Comment: did you try any of those things https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020294/error-displaying-a-winform-in-design-mode-with-a-custom-control-on-it ? seems like the designer is broken or there is something wrong with it; you can also try in another visual studio.

Comment: Doesn't look like issue with design - I tried with VS2019 as well - same issue - not sure if this event based triggers , not sure how to debug events.